# Populate select box from database using MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a website using asp.net and MVC. I need to populate a select box with values from my database and I was wondering how I would go about doing this?

Comment: could you show any effort?

Comment: I was just looking for some guidance as I am new to using asp.net and mvc

Comment: Use `Html.DropDownListFor()` in your view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways to do it, but this what I do. In my service class, I do the db select & return a SelectList object

```
public SelectList GetAsSelectList()
        {
            var depts = from d in GetAll()
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = d.Id,
                            Name = d.Name
                        };

            return new SelectList(depts, "Id", "Name");
        }
```

Then in my model, I assign the selectlist to a property:

```
model.Suppliers = _supplierService.GetAsSelectList();

return View(model);
```

And finally the View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DeliveryStoreId, Model.DeliveryStores)
```